# Mapping flat data against master data

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a table in MSSQL with master data that I have to map to objects located at the leaves of a flat tree table looking something like this:

[dbo].[flat_tree]

```
grand_grand_grand_parent | grand_grand_parent |        parent       |        leaf
           15            |         11         |          5          |         1
           15            |         11         |          5          |         2
           15            |         11         |          5          |         3
           15            |         11         |          5          |         4
```

Where I use the parent level objects together with inner joins to match them to a specific row in the master data. This is done by matching each level of the flat_tree table against some properties in other tables.

So if the master data would be something like this:

[dbo].[master_data]

```
id | a1 | a2 | a3
 8 |  1 |  5 | 4
 6 |  7 | 15 | 20
```

I would do inner joins from the parents and also leaf level object against other tables in the database and match the values against a1, a2 and a3 respectively to find out the a match in the master data for the leaf. I would then proceed to inserting the leaf and id into a match table with a many-to-many relationship:

[dbo].[mapping]

```
leaf | id
  1  |  8
  2  |  8
  1  |  6
```

Currently I just use a bunch of INNER JOINS to match the properties of the objects in [dbo].[flat_tree] against the columns in [dbo].[master_data]. Some of the properties also have string values in addition that have to be evaluated (acquired from iterating through the master data row by row) like so:

```
SELECT flat_tree.leaf
FROM [dbo].[flat_tree]

INNER JOIN [dbo].[properties1]
ON properties1.id = grand_grand_grand_parent
AND properties1.type = 6
AND properties1.stuff = 'temp'

...
```

My question is what would be the most cost efficient way of mapping the master data against the leaves?